# Delete rows based on value in two seperate columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet in which I need to delete rows where cell values in two distinct columns are BOTH the integer zero.

The script I'm running deletes rows in which EITHER cell value is zero.

Any suggestions on how the following might be modified to accomplish my need are appreciated:

```
// Add UI to run script from spreadsheet

function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Clear OI')
      .addItem('Clear OI', 'removeZeroOI')
      .addToUi();
}

// Delete rows functions

function removeZeroOI() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mySheetID");
  var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName("OI Test");
  var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
  
  var COLS_TO_SEARCH = {n:13, y:24}; // Search columns N and Y
  var DELETE_VAL = 0; // Delete rows with this cell value
  
  
  main(); 
  
  function main() {
    var deleteSelectedRows = removeFilterSetVals();        
  };

  
  function removeFilterSetVals() {
    var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
    var filteredRange = rangeVals.filter(function(val) {
      return (val[COLS_TO_SEARCH.n] != DELETE_VAL && val[COLS_TO_SEARCH.y] != DELETE_VAL)
    });
    
    RANGE.clearContent();
    var newRange = SHEET.getRange(1, 1, filteredRange.length, filteredRange[0]
      .length);
    newRange.setValues(filteredRange);
  };
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Your `filter` method's return function only accepts rows if both columns have non-zero values:

```
return (val[COLS_TO_SEARCH.n] != DELETE_VAL && val[COLS_TO_SEARCH.y] != DELETE_VAL)
```

**Solution:**

To accept zero in either of the columns you can replace the `and` operator with `or`:

```
return (val[COLS_TO_SEARCH.n] != DELETE_VAL || val[COLS_TO_SEARCH.y] != DELETE_VAL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the condition from AND to OR:

```
function removeFilterSetVals() {
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  var filteredRange = rangeVals.filter(function(val) {
    return (val[COLS_TO_SEARCH.n - 1] != DELETE_VAL || val[COLS_TO_SEARCH.y - 1] != DELETE_VAL) // if one of them non zero - keep the row
});
```

I also changed `val[COLS_TO_SEARCH.n]` to `val[COLS_TO_SEARCH.n - 1]` since google sheet row/column numbers start from 1, while array indexes starts from 0.

If you already take it in your considuration, switch it back to `val[COLS_TO_SEARCH.n]`

Comment: Thanks for commenting the column indexing - it is accounted for in the script, but appreciate the comment.